# How can I select one record (ordered by descending)?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I use LINQ-TO-SQL. And I have a control Order. And in the control I have a property OrderDetail. I only want to show the last updated data. So I have to order by ChangedAt. That's a DateTime field.

When I try to open this entity. I get an error like **Specified cast is not valid**, while I see by debugging the selection has 1 row.

How can I select one record, ordered by descending (ChangedAt)?

The relationship between both entities Order : OrderDetail <=> 1 : n.

```
partial class Order : ILock, ICloneable
{
   ...
    public OrderDetail Detail
    {
        get
        {
            var detail = this.OrderDetails.Select(od => od);

            if (detail != null && detail.Count() > 0)
                return detail.OrderByDescending(od => od.ChangedAt).FirstOrDefault();
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

I don't think it's important. But I use SQL-Server as database.

Comment: not directly related to your issue but lots of redundant code, you can simply do: `return OrderDetails.OrderByDescending(od => od.ChangedAt).FirstOrDefault();`, and since it is `FirstOrDefault` it will return `null` in case the item is not found.

Comment: `var detail = this.OrderDetails.Select(od => od);` probably you need to make a copy, not pass a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this to get the first record in the list, in descending order by `ChangedAt`:

```
public OrderDetail Detail
{
    get
    {
        return this.OrderDetails
            .OrderByDescending(od => od.ChangedAt)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Null checking in LINQ to entities/SQL is not required as the internal expression parser handles this for you.

Comment: This was my first try. But I think there is something wrong with one the properties. But thanks.